# Error: Could not read Block X of relation base/Y/Z

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

We have some serious issues with our PostgreSQL-Server (Version 8.4). Our webapplication uses jdbc to connect to the PostgreSQL Server. Suddenly our webapplication cant connect to the PostgreSQL Server. We get the PSQLException: Broken Pipe. Cause of this, i tried to connect via pg_admin. This works, but i'm getting errors like this:

> ERROR:  could not read block 32570 of relation base/16390/2663: read
> only 0 of 8192 bytes

I tried to make a dump to backup the data and this doesnt work too:
(Look on the edit at the bottom of the side)

> pg_dump: SQL command failed
>
> pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR: could not read block 32570 of relation
> base/16390/2663: read only 0 of
> 8192 bytes
>
> pg_dump: The command was: LOCK TABLE
> public.results_233_top100_disease_state_karyotype IN ACCESS SHARE MODE

I tried to get some information with

```
SELECT oid, relname FROM pg_class WHERE oid=2663
```

The result was this:

> 2663 ; "pg_class_relname_nsp_index"

During my effort of collecting some information, i read, that recreating that specific index could help. So reindexed it with the following command:

```
REINDEX INDEX pg_class_relname_nsp_index
```

This didnt helped at all, and now i'm pretty helpless. Has somebody an idea what i can do ? Another point is, that we do weekly backups. Is it possible to overwrite the data folder: `/var/lib/postgresql/8.4./main` with our data from the backup?

*EDIT*: I fixed the problem with reindexing the table that had the error. Now i'm getting another error:

> pg_dump: SQL command failed
> pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR: invalid page header in block 1047 of relation base/16390/16398
> pg_dump: The command was: COPY public.data_1 (sampleid, feature, value) TO stdout;

Comment: Just wanted to add that on my 9.2 Postgres the above  `SELECT oid, relname FROM pg_class WHERE oid=2663` always showed empty results. The select below gave the correct results `select oid, relfilenode, relname from pg_class where relfilenode = 2663` - note the 2663 is from the above example.

Comment: This question is high in search result, so I just wanted to point out that you __can__ get some data back if you set `set zero_damaged_pages = on;`. This way Postgres will skip rows that are corrupted and keep fetching forward instead of aborting query with error. I've had such corruption and recovered over 99% data.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński That has no effect for me. I'm trying to recover a corrupted table, that still has some rows that are selectable, but when I try to query the entire table, I get `ERROR:  missing chunk number 0 for toast value 151065 in pg_toast_106852`

Comment: This issue is also occurring on M1 Macs (Apple Silicon) -- in my case a MacBook Air -- without apparent corruption of the data. Accessing the same database from an Intel-based Mac results in no errors.

Answer (score 4):

Before doing *anything* else, read and act on: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption .

Most likely you have disk or file system problems.

If you suspect any kind of DB corruption for whatever reason you should *stop the DB and copy the entire database at the file system level before attempting any recovery*.

Once you've done that, then you can look into possible repairs. You'll probably have some significant data loss, so your goal should be to get it working to the point where you can `pg_dump` the damaged databases, re-initdb, and reload.

If you have a recent backup, now would be a good time to think about using it.

Comment: I understand this advice (as also listed in the postgresql wiki) but in my case because the block was corrupt I couldn't make a copy of the file. I ended up truncating the table and rebuilding the data to get things working.

Comment: @jwadsack Makes sense

Comment: This answer is unclear. Are you implying that, once the damaged database has been copied, a simple dump/load will repair the files?

Comment: @Cerin It certainly won't repair the files. You'd usually dump, *delete or move aside the corrupt database*, *initdb a new blank database* and reload into that.